I have strange issue when copy some piece of code in konsole
I have rather a strange issue on my fresh Kubuntu 22.04 installation, when I try to copy some piece of code in konsole or enter some text
in console command :
https://youtu.be/ocCnoMiy3E4
$ lsb_release -d; uname -r; uname -i
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
6.5.0-26-generic
x86_64




$ kf5-config --version
Qt: 5.15.3
KDE Frameworks: 5.92.0
kf5-config: 1.0




$ dpkg -s  konsole
Package: konsole
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: kde
Installed-Size: 4658
Maintainer: Kubuntu Developers <kubuntu-devel@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 4:21.12.3-0ubuntu1
Provides: x-terminal-emulator
Depends: konsole-kpart (= 4:21.12.3-0ubuntu1), kio, libc6 (>= 2.34), libkf5configcore5 (>= 5.71.0~), libkf5configwidgets5 (>= 5.71.0~), libkf5coreaddons5 (>= 5.71.0~), libkf5crash5 (>= 5.71.0~), libkf5dbusaddons5 (>= 5.71.0~), libkf5globalaccel-bin, libkf5globalaccel5 (>= 5.71.0~), libkf5guiaddons-bin, libkf5guiaddons5 (>= 5.71.0~), libkf5i18n5 (>= 5.71.0~), libkf5kiowidgets5 (>= 5.71.0~), libkf5notifyconfig5 (>= 5.71.0~), libkf5widgetsaddons5 (>= 5.77.0), libkf5windowsystem5 (>= 5.82.0), libkf5xmlgui5 (>= 5.71.0~), libqt5core5a (>= 5.15.1), libqt5gui5 (>= 5.15.0~) | libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.15.0~), libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.15.0~), libstdc++6 (>= 11)
Suggests: lrzsz
Description: X terminal emulator
Konsole is a terminal emulator built on the KDE Platform. It can contain
multiple terminal sessions inside one window using detachable tabs.
.
Konsole supports powerful terminal features, such as customizable schemes,
saved sessions, and output monitoring.
Homepage: https://apps.kde.org/en/konsole
Original-Maintainer: Debian Qt/KDE Maintainers <debian-qt-kde@lists.debian.org>

Why I got it and how it can be fixed ?

Can you describe in words exactly what you did and the result of your action as well as what you expected would happen. A YouTube video is not that useful when I can't read what it says on your terminal.

I try 1) to select some text in terminal to copy it 2) To enter some text in console text. Sorry I do not know how exactly to call this strange effect - like entry point was some distance rigth from place where I enter text

I would suggest testing another terminal emulator like xterm. It seems to me, you are using some script (may be the one used to show current working path) in bash rc or profile file that is not compatible with konsole line wrap or may be BiDi algorithm.

Content of which files have I to check ? I did not modify any files of original installation.

you can use recovery mode to reinstall the Konsole

Could you please explain why have I to use "recovery mode" to reinstall konsole app ?

I tried to installand use xterm - but found it very unconvinient. Are there some other alternative console app which I cab use in kubuntu 22.04?
